# Rear camera on mobile using HTML5 / JS

Tags: javascript, android, html, camera, webcam

Finally I have a working script which enables me to access camera both on desktop on mobile. However on mobile I would like to use the rear camera primarily.

I tried with facingMode: environment, but it doesn't work.

Here is the link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3y8k7t4/) and the code I have:

```
     function startcam() {

        // Grab elements, create settings, etc.
        var video = document.getElementById('video');
        var mediaConfig =  { video: true };
        var errBack = function(e) {
            console.log('An error has occurred!', e)
        };

        // Put video listeners into place
        if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(mediaConfig).then(function(stream) {
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            });
        }

        /* Legacy code below! */
        else if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
            navigator.getUserMedia(mediaConfig, function(stream) {
                video.src = stream;
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(mediaConfig, function(stream){
                video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        } else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Mozilla-prefixed
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia(mediaConfig, function(stream){
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                video.play();
            }, errBack);
        };

 };
 startcam();
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say you have tried `facingMode: "environment" `, are you requiring it or just preferring it? I presume you're following [this MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)?

Comment: I would require it. Yes, I tried with changing mediaConfig, but it doesn't work: var mediaConfig =  { video: { facingMode: "environment" } };

Comment: The MDN documentation says that if you require it, you should be using `var mediaConfig = {  video: { facingMode: { exact: "environment" } } }`. Does that work?

Comment: It doesn't work. On mobile chrome still using the front-facing camera, on desktop it doesn't even show up.

Comment: Have you tried passing the parameters in directly rather than through as a variable? The parameters may be coming through as a string rather than as a JSON object and therefore the `getUserMedia()` method may not be receiving anything. Alternatively try using `JSON.parse()` and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck, it doesn't even show up the user-facing camera... Tried with JSON.parse("{ video: {facingMode: { exact: "environment" }}}"). I guess it would be the same with using it directly.

Comment: Try `var mediaConfig =  JSON.parse('{"video": true }');`. I suspect it is related to the format of your JSON.

Comment: It works with the front-facing camera again. Somehow it has to be reformated to use environment.

Comment: Yes, so for the rear camera it would be `var mediaConfig =  JSON.parse('{ "video": { "facingMode": { "exact": "environment" } } }');`

Comment: No luck with this.

Comment: What error are you receiving? I'm getting `DOMException: Requested device not found` because I do not have a webcam connected to my PC.

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) NavigatorUserMediaError.. Because my laptop only has a front-facing webcam.. On my mobile I still see only front camera.

Answer (score 3):

This works well in chrome for android

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ 
  video: { 
    facingMode: { exact: "environment" }
  } 
})
.then(function(stream) {
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  video.play();
});
```

Comment: Also, in Safari in IOS.